Why is Anarchism not considered fundamentally against the "democratic order" in Germany?
In Germany organizations and or parties that promote National Socialism (openly) are illegal per §130 Stgb and Article 9 abs. 2 GG.
Reasons are that National Socialism fundamentally is incompatible with the so called liberal democratic order.
In this case why is the ideology of Anarchism and the promotion of it not considered illegal per German law, as it promotes the abolishment of the state?

Is this a purely academic question?  As far as I know, no organisations promoting Anarchism currently exist in Germany.

Anarchism in general is not about abolishment of the state. It is about needlessness of the government in the case when every human being does what is needed without enforcement from above. From this point of view, anarchism is the highest form of democracy, when the people are ruled by themselves.

@gerrit Oh there are.
https://www.dieplattform.org/
https://www.fau.org/
https://fda-ifa.org/

@user13964273
The definition of Anarchism means:
political theory
a doctrine advocating the abolition of government
2. the principles or practice of anarchists
https://www.collinsdictionary.com/de/worterbuch/englisch/anarchism
With abolishing the state you also abolish the constitution and that would be fundamentally anti-constituional according to those laws:  Art. 9 Abs. 2 GG, § 83 StGB, § 81.
It doenst matter how democratic you may see your actions doing it.
Also other Anarchist may disagree.
theanarchistlibrary.org/library/wayne-price-the-abolition-of-the-state

Could you please define Anarchism, just so that we know that we're all reading form the same book when we answer.

@AaarghZombies  Anarchism  a doctrine urging the abolition of government or governmental restraint as the indispensable condition for full social and political liberty.  https://www.collinsdictionary.com/de/worterbuch/englisch/anarchism

Every political system naturally protect itself. Abolishing of slavery had a strong opposition but finally won. Current POV that people belong to the state is also kinda slavery.

@Questioner: Pure anarchists don't intend to abolish the constitution, they seek to enshrine that power is divided across the populace. That is a constitution, just one with a different content. They're vying for a change to the constitution, not to abolish the entire concept.

More broadly, your interpretation of anarchism diverges from the general definition in that it conflates "abolishing the government" and "abolishing this type of government", which is born from an assumption that only this type of government is the only allowed one. That sort of self-imposement where the government mandates that it is the only allowed form of government is the core reason for the friction between current governments and anarchists. Democracy, at its roots, would allow a shift into anarchy if anarchy has majority support - thus making it not undemocratic.

Semantically, "government" does not inherently mean "the select few with power to govern everyone else" (even though that is currently how a lot of nations operate). "Government" refers to how the populace governs itself, and anarchy is a form of government (just not one that's in active use at the moment). Democrats and anarchists both believe that the entire (adult) populace should have a say in how they govern themselves - they simply disagree on whether they need a select group to represent and execute the will of the people (democrats) or not (anarchists).

You are missing a few relevant laws. Notably §84, §85, §86 and 86a StGB.
§84 and §85 criminalise the continuation of any prohibited party or organisation, while §86 and §86a criminalise the distribution of their materials and usage of their symbols.
Which parties and organisations are prohibited are outlined in Art 21 GG and §3 VereinsG respectively.
They state:

Parties that, by reason of their aims or the behaviour of their adherents, seek to undermine or abolish the free democratic basic order or to endanger the existence of the Federal Republic of Germany shall be unconstitutional.

and

Ein Verein darf erst dann als verboten (Artikel 9 Abs. 2 des Grundgesetzes) behandelt werden, wenn durch Verfügung der Verbotsbehörde festgestellt ist, daß seine Zwecke oder seine Tätigkeit den Strafgesetzen zuwiderlaufen oder daß er sich gegen die verfassungsmäßige Ordnung oder den Gedanken der Völkerverständigung richtet


An organisation may only be treated as prohibited (Article 9 (2) of the Basic Law) if it has been established by order of the prohibition authority1 that its purposes or activities are contrary to criminal law or that it is directed against the constitutional order or the idea of international understanding

This definition could include anarchist organisations. So far, one left-wing 2 organisation has been prohibited under this law. In 2017, the federal government prohibited linksunten.indymedia, an aggregate news site. The decision was controversial but held up in court
One forbidden organisation is not much, but the hurdles are quite high as well. It is not enough for all members of the organisation to want to abolish the FDGO (Freiheitlich Demokratische Grundordnung or "liberal democratic basic order") or commit crimes, the organisation itself needs to have that aim. As anarchists tend to be quite loosely organized with the actual organisations being cultural centers, mutual aid organisations or anti-fascist research groups, there isn't much to go on. There are still a number of anarchists groups mentioned in the yearly report of the Office for Protection of the Constitution, which is responsible for collecting the evidence needed for a probibition. Apparently the evidence is not sufficient to support a full ban. You can read the report (in German) for more information on the various groups that the government is investigating.
This may also be, because the FDGO is more opposed to right-wing instead of anarchist extremism.
In its decision denying the prohibition of the right-wing party NPD, the Constitutional Court set out what the FDGO entails (emphasis mine):

a) The free democratic basic order is rooted primarily in human dignity (Art. 1(1) GG). The guarantee of human dignity covers in particular the safeguarding of personal individuality, identity and integrity and elementary equality before the law.
b) Furthermore, the principle of democracy is a constitutive element of the free democratic basic order. The possibility of equal participation by all citizens in the process of forming the political will as well as accountability to the people for the exercise of state authority (Art. 20(1) and (2) GG) are indispensable for a democratic system.
c) Finally, the concept of the free democratic basic order is further determined by the principle that organs of the state be bound by the law (Art. 20(3) GG) - a principle which is rooted in the principle of the rule of law, and by independent courts’ oversight in that regard. At the same time, protection of the freedom of individuals requires that the use of physical force is reserved for the organs of the state which are bound by the law and subject to judicial oversight.

Anarchists tend to support human dignity, they tend to support the principle of democracy (although they tend to promote different implementations than liberals). The only place where they oppose the FDGO would be with regard to the rule of law and the state monopoly on violence. Importantly, a monopoly on state violence does not mean that the state must be violent. It would be perfectly within the FDGO to eliminate all state violence, as long as no other violence takes its place. It is up to you, whether you believe that to be possible but if anarchists do, they do not violate the FDGO.
Also, an anarchist organisation would have to actually organisationally work against the FDGO to be a candidate for prohibition. It is not enough that many of its members want to achieve that goal, unless they use the group to organise to that specific effect. Front-facing anarchist organisations are focussed on things like legal support for protestors, labour unions or mutual aid networks (as mentioned by Simon Richter), all of which aren't actually unconstitutional. The dubious stuff that might actively oppose the FDGO tends to happen in smaller, unorganized groups.

A note on §130 StGB
§130 is a separate law, specifically against hate speech, which in Germany explicitly includes praise of the Nazi regime or denial of its crimes.
However, subsections 1 and 2 deal with calls for violence or grave insults against racial, national, ethnic or religious groups in general, while subsection 5 deals with genocide denial in general, so the prohibition does not exclusively target Nazis. Also, it does not stop you from joining Nazi groups, as long as you keep that involvement to yourself.
Also, §130 StGB is not there to protect the Freiheitlich-Demokratische Grundordnung (FDGO, the liberal democratic order mentioned in the question). Instead the protected good is the dignity of the targeted people. As such, there is no prohibition against publicly calling for the establishment of a dictatorship or the abolition of the entire state. Such statements would only be illegal under §130 StGB, if they also included attacks against the aforementioned groups.
Prohibited speech by anarchists is unlikely to fall under that, because even violent anarchists tend to pick their targets on the basis of their political alignment, occupation or wealth and not on the basis of race or religion. Anarchist speech is more likely to fall under §140 StGB which prohibits publicly praising violent criminal acts.

There are also §80, §82, §83 StGB, which deal with treason and the usage of violence to abolish the constitutional order or inhibit the existence of a state.
And §105 and §106 StGB which deal with violence or threats of violence used to compell action or inaction from a constitutional body or members thereof. The latter would deal with things like a bomb threat on the Bundestag to force its members not to vote for a certain law.
These could also apply to anarchists, especially if they use violence to abolish the state. However, it is unlikely that anarchists are convicted under any of these (except for §106, which applies to individual people), as the courts have a narrow definition of violence against constitutional bodies.
In particular, the BGH (which is the highest criminal court in Germany) swrote the following in its decision BGHSt 23, 46 (regarding blockades of tram lines in 1966):

Das Urteil darüber, ob ein tatsächlicher Vorgang als Gewalt im Sinne eines bestimmten strafrechtlichen Tatbestandes anzusehen ist, läßt sich nicht einfach dadurch gewinnen, daß dieser Vorgang an einer abstrakten Umschreibung des Gewaltbegriffs gemessen wird. Solch isolierte Betrachtung ist verfehlt; der Vorgang ist stets im Zusammenhang mit dem vom Tatbestand vorausgesetzten Ziel des Handelns und in seinem Verhältnis zu der Person oder den Personen zu beurteilen, die betroffen oder beeinflußt werden sollen. Es genügt also nicht, daß eine zur Überwindung irgendeines Widerstandes geeignete Kraft entfaltet wird, sondern es kommt wesentlich auf die spezifische Eignung dieser Kraft im Sinne ihrer vom Tatbestand vorausgesetzten Wirksamkeit an.


The judgement as to whether an actual event is to be regarded as violence in the sense of a specific criminal offence cannot be made simply by measuring this event against an abstract description of the concept of violence. Such an isolated view is misguided; the act must always be judged in connection with the objective of the action presupposed by the offence and in its relationship to the person or persons who are to be affected or influenced. It is therefore not sufficient that a force suitable for overcoming any resistance is deployed, but it is essentially a matter of the specific suitability of this force in the sense of its effectiveness presupposed by the offence.

This horribly convoluted piece of legal writing basically says that acts against constitutional bodies have to actually be able to affect these bodies to be considered violence. Torching cars or even attacking some police officers would not be enough to constitute violence against the constitutional order, the scale is too small. Of course, torching cars or attacking police officers are crimes(§306 and §114 StGB respectively), just not crimes against the constitutional order. German anarchists are nowhere near the level where their acts would actually threaten the constitutional order.

1: The prohibition authority is the federal ministry of the interior or the equivalent agency in one of the states. the decision can be appealed at an administrative court.
2: Anarchism is more complicated than a left-right distinction, this answer will talk about left-wing anarchism. The closest thing to right-wing anarchists would be the so called "Selbstverwalter" (sovereign citizens). However, in Germany, they are closely linked to the Reichsbürger movement which is decidedly authoritarian and wants a return to the German Empire.

This may also be, because the FDGO is more opposed to right-wing instead of anarchist extremism — tell that to Mr. Maaßen...

@gerrit One guy no guy.
The general trend was and is that the FDGO was used against more right-wing groups. This can be seen in the Verfassungsschutzbericht right down in the "VERBOTSMASSNAHMEN" Sektion.
Just because one man decided to concentrate a little bit on a different political side doesn't mean its generally used against you as it should.

Can these laws perhaps be used against Anarchist?
§§ 81, 82 StGB, § 83 StGB.

@Questioner I included these laws in a new edit

@Questioner One guy? That one guy was the president of the Verfassungsschutz... He was in charge of that institution and he's not "a little bit on a different political side", his own former institution ranks him as FAR RIGHT EXTREMIST... and he's by far not the only guy who left that position with a far right scandal to their resume. Like the guys who botched the NPD ban by basically financing that party, to involvement of informants in far right terrorism and shreddering evidence when being investigated and that's just recent years

@Questioner used against you as it should - Yes, left-wing extremists are less likely to be targeted by the BfV but my answer argues that that is because they are less likely to violate the FDGO in the first place. You've indicated below another answer that you don't like the focus on human dignity but, whether you like it or not, it is the foundation of Germany's constitutional order. The right-wing utopia of an ethnostate would violate human dignity, the left-wing anarchist utopia of complete self-governance would not.

Sovereign citizens are probably the least sophisticated movement that is similar to anarchism. They reject certain laws or government institutions while making far-fetched arguments in support of cherry-picked laws or government institutions that they do like. In many cases, these are old laws that are no longer officially valid or are no longer de facto applied. Sovereign citizens also insist that their own interpretations of law and pseudo-legal arguments are correct, even though making such arguments in court is unlikely to be successful.

I don't see sovereign citizens to be inherently right-wing or left-wing. Their views are incoherent and may mix some right-wing and left-wing concepts.

Anarcho-capitalism is the prime example of right-wing anarchism. Both the US and Europe have anarcho-capitalist organisations. It is unlikely that a government would prohibit anarcho-capitalist organisations because the ideology rejects violence, including political violence and revolutions.

I should note that my comments regarding sovereign citizens above are descriptive of sovereign citizens in the US and the UK. I don't have any knowledge about the Selbstverwalter ideology in Germany.

@xyldke Though worth mentioning that this is just the theory. In practice the Verfassungsschutz was build up on Nazi organizations and for the longest time was tasked to combat communism and while the famous examples of left wing terrorism in Germany actually went to war with the state, while the famous examples for right wing terrorism murdered individual migrants. So left wing extremism often gets taken serious while right wing extremism is often ignored as "just individual criminals" as it's not a good PR for Germany to have nazis.

German gov't can declare a social movement as "hostile to the constitution" by Article 9 of the Basic Law. The Federal Constitutional Court can declare political parties as "hostile to the constitution" by Article 21 (2). This was done in 1952 against the neo-Nazi Social Reich party and in 1956 against the Communist Party of Germany which forcibly dissolved them, prohibited the founding of any successor organizations and withdrew all Bundestag and Landtag mandates, and seized the assets of the parties.
It was also tried in 2003 and 2017 against the far-right National Democratic Party, but the constitutional court did not ban it because according to the top judge:

The NPD pursues anti-constitutional goals but at the moment there is
an insufficient weight of evidence to make it appear possible that
their behavior will result in success

So, if the Federal Constitutional Court determines that any party or social movement like the anarchists are possibly able to succeed in undermining the Constitution/Basic Law or overthrowing German liberal democratic basic order, then they will outlaw it. They can but they don't consider it a threat large enough to proscribe in the constitution specifically, as it had done with Nazism, considering the constitution was written post-WW2 when Germany was national socialist.

I'd make it "possibly able to succeed" rather than "likely able to succed." The movement would only have to pose a credible threat, not an overwhelming one.

Note that there's a difference between the 2003 and 2017 cases: in 2003, the case was dismissed without rendering a judgment because of the "V-Männer-Skandal", so the court actually never even considered whether or not the NPD was "hostile to the constitution" or not.

Your last sentence sounds off, it reads like Germany was national socialist (ie Nazi) post WW2, which I assume is not what you intended to say?

@quarague Maybe not exactly what they intended to say, but what do you think, that all the Nazis were killed off  in 1945? Germany was still just as much nazi after surrendering as before.

@Nobody Some committed suicide, some flew to Argentina, some were hanged, quite some pursuit successful careers in politics and economics... And a whole bunch decided simply not to talk about their role in the system all too loud for at least a few year and the other silent people understood not to ask too loud about it either. So it took until their children to really ask about those parts.

In that sense the 1952 SRP might actually be called a Nazi party as those were still original Nazis and the "disguise" was barely present so little that warrants a "neo" or "new" label in front of it.

The state bans and abolishes and or even arrest people that are much smaller and "comparably" less dangerous to the constitution.
Like vereine or publications, like they did with Compact GMBH, Free Palestine Duisburg and or smaller Reichcitzens connection.
The matter of "success" is irrelevant when it comes to those topics.

@Questioner The other way around, parties usually have a higher level of protection than just Vereine or whatnot which can pop in and out of existence much easier.

Interesting how it shows the liberals in Germany ban anything they consider a real political threat, but they let groups they regard as impotent remain in the picture, so that the banning mechanism is not seen to exist as frequently as it otherwise would be seen.

The German government can declare an association to be "hostile to the constitution". Check out §3 Vereinsgesetz. However, that declaration can be challenged in court and would have to fulfill similar criteria. I don't believe, prominence is required for these declarations. Political parties enjoy special protections (but they also have to act as political parties, so they need to run in elections and fulfill certain formal criteria)

I love this answer because it's not dissimilar to how Russia solved their LGBTQ and childfree-related problems, except they actually decided "fudge it, we ball", decreed them as "organisations" and banned them anyway. I wonder what a legal breakdown of that would look like, except I think it'd boil up to "it's not legal, but they did it anyway"

@Gallifreyan That makes no sense as the punishment for an organization is the dissolution of the organization, further crimes would need further crimes. So banning an organization only makes sense if people are already officially organized and profit from that, idk pooled money, being a "legal entity" that idk holds assets, does business, pays reduced taxes etc, that is supported by the state and so on. Like sure you could call it a criminal organization point to a criminal and then punish all associates, but if you're able to get away with that bullshit, you can get away with anything.

@haxor789 preaching to the choir here: the "Male State", the LGBTQ+, the "childfree", and Jehovah's Witnesses have all been decreed as "extremist organisations" and banned in Russia. Not sure if anyone's been prosecuted for spreading "childfree ideology" yet, but I wouldn't be surprised, and it's easy enough to dig up stories of people who were prosecuted for being associated with LGBT in one way or another, a Russian human rights watchdogs counted at least 12 cases so far.

As a German anarchist: we are very democratic, and fairly realistic about how most people are not capable of self-organization in the absence of a strong state that curtails their freedoms for the greater good. Abolition of the state can only be achieved through consensus, and such consensus can only be achieved if the drawbacks of being organized as a state outweigh the benefits.
Anarchist organization against the state thus consists of building mutual aid networks that reduce the utility of the state.
The state does, quite heavy-handedly, oppose efforts to self-organize, and police will often raid soup kitchens or womens' shelters if they are not attached to an organization that is visible to and integrated with the state, because they would prefer a less democratic, less mutual and more controllable distribution of aid.
It is however difficult for the state to argue that replacing the state with more democratic and less centralized structures is an anti-democratic act, and the drafters of the basic law were not overly concerned with that either, quite the opposite: what the state needs to protect itself from is capture by anti-democratic forces.
The paragraphs you quote is one line of defense here, assuming working democratic institutions and giving them the necessary legal standing to be proactive.
The basic law also provides a fallback if democratic institutions fail, preemptively legalizing a (possibly anarchist) uprising under rather narrow conditions that we all are working hard to avoid.

Can you give a source for your claim: "police will often raid soup kitchens or womens' shelters"?

That is kind of difficult with "reputable" sources -- if you read about any of this in a newspaper, it will be written from the point of view of the police.

Point of view of the police would be fine, it would still confirm that such raids happen and happen often which I have doubts about because I've never heard about any such raids. Whether the raid was justified or not of course depends on the point of view and the police will not be neutral here.

@SimonRichter Germany does have reputable news outlets what will report the perspective of the ones raided.  The Berlin part of the taz is still quite leftist and usually won't uncritically copy-paste a police press release.

@quarague Lützerath in January 2023, I seem to recall, though I can't find good coverage of it; and I'm not sure it's a great example, because there were other reasons for the police raid.

@quarague Yeah they always represent those raids, ignoring certain context like it being squatted or being part of illegal organization.
They don't apply the same logic to raids done on Neonazis for example.

"an organization that is visible to and integrated with the state". What does that mean? To some extent every person and every organization is "visible to and integrated with the state".

@DJClayworth For example you could just meet with some friends and set up a soup kitchen. That would be a form of organization that flies somewhat below the radar. However you could also form a social club (if you have at least 7 members you can found one) and do it officially as a group. Then you'd have tax benefits, a club constitution, membership fees, a cause, be eligible for donations (that allow tax benefits for the donor) and whatnot. Also if you give out food, the Ordnungsamt might check whether that food is safe whether you comply with hygiene standards and whatnot.

In Germany you have Meinungsfreiheit (freedom of opinion):

(1) Every person shall have the right freely to express and disseminate his opinions in speech, writing and pictures and to inform himself without hindrance from generally accessible sources. Freedom of the press and freedom of reporting by means of broadcasts and films shall be guaranteed. There shall be no censorship.


(2) These rights shall find their limits in the provisions of general laws, in provisions for the protection of young persons and in the right to personal honour.

So in general the line of reasoning is NOT that certain ideologies are illegal. The line of reasoning is that freedom of expression finds its limits if you violate the law and/or the rights and freedoms of other people.
So if you read §130 StGB (German penal code) carefully you'll see that this actually refers to "incitement of the masses"

(1) Whoever, in a manner suited to causing a disturbance of the public peace,



incites hatred against a national, racial, religious group or a group defined by their ethnic origin, against sections of the population or individuals on account of their belonging to one of the aforementioned groups or sections of the population, or calls for violent or arbitrary measures against them or




violates the human dignity of others by insulting, maliciously maligning or defaming one of the aforementioned groups, sections of the population or individuals on account of their belonging to one of the aforementioned groups or sections of the population



incurs a penalty of imprisonment for a term of between three months and five years.

So the main point isn't about abolishing national socialism as much as protecting the "inviolable right to dignity" explicitly stated in Article 1 of the German constitution.

(1) Human dignity shall be inviolable. To respect and protect it shall be the duty of all state authority.


(2) The German people therefore acknowledge inviolable and inalienable human rights as the basis of every community, of peace and of justice in the world.


(3) The following basic rights shall bind the legislature, the executive and the judiciary as directly applicable law.

Now how you'd do fascism without demonizing an other, idk, but that is their problem, not one of any law abiding citizen.
Now to be fair subsections (3) and (4) directly target disturbing the public peace by (3) downplaying nazi crimes or (4) glorifying the nazi reign, but again neither targets any ideology explicitly.
Of course talking about "a great nation in decline" and how previously "everything has been great before the degeneracy of the democratic system" and other fascist tropes, is a tough sale with the Nazis and WWII in the history books, but there are few historic fact more established, researched and corroborated by evidence.
So if you have to value the dignity of the victims of the Nazi crimes against Neo-nazi aspiration to lie about history, well Germany made a rather obvious decision.
On top of that §86 and §86a StGB specify the dissemination and public display of propaganda material of parties who received a final verdict of being unconstitutional. Which obviously famously applies to original Nazi party NSDAP as well as their sub-organizations.
That's why you can't do Hitler salutes, show swastikas or whatnot. Though that is also just meant for their usage for promotional usage or lack of context, whereas "to prevent unconstitutional activities, to promote the arts or science, research or teaching, reporting about current or historical events, or similar purposes." is not a crime. So history books and non fascist documentaries and whatnot might still show original footage or whatnot without going to jail.
Now Germans also have a right to assemble.

Article 8 [Freedom of assembly]


(1) All Germans shall have the right to assemble peacefully and unarmed without prior notification or permission.

and a freedom to associate and form groups and parties:

Article 9[Freedom of association]


(1) All Germans shall have the right to form societies and other associations.


(2) Associations whose aims or activities contravene the criminal laws or that are directed against the constitutional order or the concept of international understanding shall be prohibited.

So (2) forbids associations with the goal to do criminal stuff or overthrow the constitution. You still have freedom of opinion though, that is just getting into practical matters.
On top of the mere association you can also form political parties:

Article 21 [Political parties]


(1) Political parties shall participate in the formation of the political will of the people. They may be freely established. Their internal organisation must conform to democratic principles. They must publicly account for their assets and for the sources and use of their funds.


(2) Parties that, by reason of their aims or the behaviour of their adherents, seek to undermine or abolish the free democratic basic order or to endanger the existence of the Federal Republic of Germany shall be unconstitutional.


(3) Parties that, by reason of their aims or the behaviour of their adherents, are oriented towards an undermining or abolition of the free democratic basic order or an endangerment of the existence of the Federal Republic of Germany shall be excluded from state financing. If such exclusion is determined, any favourable fiscal treatment of these parties and of payments made to those parties shall cease.


(4) The Federal Constitutional Court shall rule on the question of unconstitutionality within the meaning of paragraph (2) of this Article and on exclusion from state financing within the meaning of paragraph (3).


(5) Details shall be regulated by federal laws.

Which are more established organization with rights and duties, that are required to be internally democratic and which must not seek to undermine the "Freiheitlich Demokratische Grundordnung" (liberal democratic basic order, though liberal in the sense of concerning individual liberty not some economic liberalism) or endanger the state itself. If they do, their funding and favorable fiscal treatment is discontinued and their name symbols or whatnot become subject to §84-§86a StGB (continuation despite ban, forming of a successor despite ban, propaganda, usage of symbols).
Which apparently also includes the successor to the NSDAP the SRP and the communist party of Germany KPD, which technically also means that the KPD letters as well as the hammer and sickle are banned. Though practically it's really weird (German source), because apparently since the Democratic Republic of Germany joined the Federal Republic of Germany, with all their parties and organizations (including the KPD which together with the SPD formed a new party the SED), there's now both a legal and an illegal KPD, also as hammer and sickle are also symbols used world wide without reference to a particular German party only the usage in that particular context is illegal.
So again it's not the really any particular ideology that is banned but rather concrete crimes and organizations with the aim to commit crimes. Though to be fair given that democracy is a pretty leftist concept to begin with Neo-Nazis are just more prone to violate the law in general and avoiding to violate the law would almost require them not to be National Socialists, which is fully intended, but doesn't require a specific ideological ban.
On the other hand Anarchism, so the idea that nobody should rule over other people, simply doesn't have much of those intrinsic problems. So inciting racism, sexism, homophobia, xenophobia and so on simply isn't part of the anarchist agenda and would actually violate their own principles before violating the laws.
Also as anarchists often have a problem with rigid organizational structures, those bans on parties and clubs are way less likely to affect them, in that regard as they don't usually organize as such in the first place.
There are organizations like anarcho-syndicalist unions like the FAU, but as long as they are busy doing union stuff and don't try to overthrow the government, they are on the radar of the Verfassungsschutz (police tasked with the protection of the constitution) but they aren't necessarily an immediate necessity to intervene.
So what is more likely is that individuals are arrested for crimes outside of the political movement or for violations of laws due to acting outside of the legal context. But as long as there's no revolutionary violence the state is suspicious of them and count them as left-wing extremism due to their tendency to so radically being in favor of democracy that they would ultimately also are antagonistic to the state itself, but unless that cannot be tied to actual crimes, it's not illegal per se.
Also there's the distinction between anti-constitutional and unconstitutional where it's within your freedom of opinion to be against the constitution, as otherwise you'd never be able to change it, that being said, there are legal ways to change it and going outside of that framework marks something unconstitutional and thus subject to the criminal law, including bans and whatnot.
So TL;DR Anarchists are less likely to violate the law (with regards to human dignity and being against freedom and democracy (on the contrary)), and where they violate the law they usually aren't organized in criminal organizations that can be effectively banned. Sure some "Autonome" may be linked to petty crimes and vandalism, but that's not really the "effective aim to dismantle the state" or "incitement of violence and disturbance of the public peace" or if their effective means to dismantle the state involve demonstrations, educating about democracy and practicing democratic forms of organization, then the goal might be problematic but all of the actions are perfectly legal, even explicitly allowed in the constitution and often encouraged in a democratic system. So where even neo-fascist organizations are granted those rights with the benefit of the doubt, before proving they are unconstitutional, it's hard to argue in that direction.
And even where it militant you need to link them to a specific project that you want to ban, otherwise you can only target the individual not the collective.

"In Germany you have Meinungsfreiheit"
Defacto and dejure I would disagree. Again, due to the expansions of article §130 and other laws limiting things you can say or promote, a lot of things a simply illegal to say or do. Its not Russia but it is strict if you go to certain areas of controversy or offense.
HDJ got banned due being "internally close" to National Socialism.
"Article 1"
Yeah I hate this useless law. Human dignity is utterly subjective and is not applied equally for everybody. But to go back to the topic. While some ideologies are dejure legal they can be criminalized defac

@Questioner That you can't say and do everything is an intrinsic fundamental problem with the concept of freedom, as freedom is always also the freedom of other people, so unlimited freedom for one is no freedom for anybody else and hence no longer freedom, but merely privilege. And yes a youth organization firming under DHJ or HDJ is already close the original HJ (Hitler Youth) and with personal overlap with already forbidden organizations and proximity to actual Nazi organizations (violations of §86/§86a aso), that is not really a surprise.

@Questioner 2/ What? You hate that humans have dignity? Also how is that law useless? People have a constitutionally backed right to their dignity so whenever someone violates that you can take it to court and not on some obscure law that no one heard of but on the basis of the first article of the constitution, that's fairly powerful. So even if there's plenty of violations of human dignity, having a legal leverage against that is not useless at all.

@Questioner 3/ Sure, as said it's hard to imagine Nazi organizations that fully comply with the law, given that they are fundamentally opposed to many of the core ideas of democracy such as universal freedom and equality (at least in legally and with regards to dignity) of all people. So yeah de facto they are much more prone to get in trouble with the law. But then again is that a problem? Like in order to have democracy you'd need to restrict tyranny, but that's not a loss that's a good thing.

not human dignity per se simply the law. As it is an utterly subjective value a person has. Your dignity is damaged cause a camera took a pic of you in a public place: you poor baby. Youre dignity is damaged due you not allowed basically to defend yourself. Sucks to be you. Actual dignity is not protected, but the law is still used to make the society less safe. It's the purest virtue signal in paper form

@Questioner: You appear to deny the notion of human dignity as it's protected by the German constitution. No wonder that you oppose article 1 ! It is directly intended to counter such denial of human dignity.

@MSalters Alright can you define this so called dignity? Is there any legal definition for this word? Those dignity include things defending your honour as per your cultural norms? The dignity of having a quiet school environment? The dignity to use the bathroom without the opposite sex? Where does it start and where does it end?

@Questioner: That's another basic rule in most law systems, Germany included. Law is not philosophy or mathematics, it deals with actual cases. We do not require an upfront, full and provable definition of every word.

Realistically, the main reason it seems that way is simply that anarchism has never been a mass movement or perceived as a threat to the German state, at least in the second half of the 20th century. Whether it is compatible with the “liberal democratic order” is not merely an academic question for the state. It's mostly used to justify expanding resources fighting it (intelligence and police surveillance, legal proceedings) and curtailing public liberties.
Furthermore, the main concern of the framers of the German “Basic law” was to protect the electoral system based on the notion that the Nazis were able to use the institutions of the Weimar Republic to come to power. Anarchists do not typically engage much with electoral politics so preventing them from partaking in elections is not a priority.
On the other hand, it is not the case that the German state has been exclusively or primarily concerned with fighting (neo-)nazism. In particular after banning the Sozialistische Reichspartei in 1952, the focus quickly moved to the communist party (KPD). Its ban in 1956 was followed by the seizure of party property, the closures of many organizations deemed affiliated with the party, numerous investigations and a purge of the civil service.
On a lower level, anarchism and the “autonomous scene” are certainly within the scope of surveillance by the Federal Office for the Protection of the Constitution or everyday police repression, together with Islamists and Kurdish and Palestinian organizations (Aus­lands­be­zo­ge­ner Ex­tre­mis­mus).
